# How to avoid repeating code when creating a grid of buttons?

Tags: python

I am currently learning tkinter and wrote a code which creates a grid of 100 buttons which when clicked it disappears (I am yet to code that). However as seen below it is really inefficient. Is there any way to make this better and faster to write as I have coded each and every buttons with 1a,1b... and I want to know if there is a better way to do this.
The project aim is to create a 10*10 board with buttons on each square and when clicked they disappear.

```
# !/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Battleships")


def buttonClick():
    COMMAND= True
    if COMMAND == True:
        del button1a

    
# Creating the buttons
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/lukas/Downloads/Battleships boats/AircraftCarrier.png"))
label1 = Label(image=image1)
label1.place(x=40, y=10)
button1a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick) 
button1b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button1c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button1d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button1e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button1f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button1g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button1h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button1i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button1j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button2j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button3j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button4j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button5j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button6j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button7j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button8j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button9j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10a = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10b = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10c = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10d = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10e = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10f = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10g = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10h = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10i = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
button10j = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)


# Placing buttons onto the board
button1a.grid(row=1, column=1)
button1b.grid(row=1, column=2)
button1c.grid(row=1, column=3)
button1d.grid(row=1, column=4)
button1e.grid(row=1, column=5)
button1f.grid(row=1, column=6)
button1g.grid(row=1, column=7)
button1h.grid(row=1, column=8)
button1i.grid(row=1, column=9)
button1j.grid(row=1, column=10)
button2a.grid(row=2, column=1)
button2b.grid(row=2, column=2)
button2c.grid(row=2, column=3)
button2d.grid(row=2, column=4)
button2e.grid(row=2, column=5)
button2f.grid(row=2, column=6)
button2g.grid(row=2, column=7)
button2h.grid(row=2, column=8)
button2i.grid(row=2, column=9)
button2j.grid(row=2, column=10)
button3a.grid(row=3, column=1)
button3b.grid(row=3, column=2)
button3c.grid(row=3, column=3)
button3d.grid(row=3, column=4)
button3e.grid(row=3, column=5)
button3f.grid(row=3, column=6)
button3g.grid(row=3, column=7)
button3h.grid(row=3, column=8)
button3i.grid(row=3, column=9)
button3j.grid(row=3, column=10)
button4a.grid(row=4, column=1)
button4b.grid(row=4, column=2)
button4c.grid(row=4, column=3)
button4d.grid(row=4, column=4)
button4e.grid(row=4, column=5)
button4f.grid(row=4, column=6)
button4g.grid(row=4, column=7)
button4h.grid(row=4, column=8)
button4i.grid(row=4, column=9)
button4j.grid(row=4, column=10)
button5a.grid(row=5, column=1)
button5b.grid(row=5, column=2)
button5c.grid(row=5, column=3)
button5d.grid(row=5, column=4)
button5e.grid(row=5, column=5)
button5f.grid(row=5, column=6)
button5g.grid(row=5, column=7)
button5h.grid(row=5, column=8)
button5i.grid(row=5, column=9)
button5j.grid(row=5, column=10)
button6a.grid(row=6, column=1)
button6b.grid(row=6, column=2)
button6c.grid(row=6, column=3)
button6d.grid(row=6, column=4)
button6e.grid(row=6, column=5)
button6f.grid(row=6, column=6)
button6g.grid(row=6, column=7)
button6h.grid(row=6, column=8)
button6i.grid(row=6, column=9)
button6j.grid(row=6, column=10)
button7a.grid(row=7, column=1)
button7b.grid(row=7, column=2)
button7c.grid(row=7, column=3)
button7d.grid(row=7, column=4)
button7e.grid(row=7, column=5)
button7f.grid(row=7, column=6)
button7g.grid(row=7, column=7)
button7h.grid(row=7, column=8)
button7i.grid(row=7, column=9)
button7j.grid(row=7, column=10)
button8a.grid(row=8, column=1)
button8b.grid(row=8, column=2)
button8c.grid(row=8, column=3)
button8d.grid(row=8, column=4)
button8e.grid(row=8, column=5)
button8f.grid(row=8, column=6)
button8g.grid(row=8, column=7)
button8h.grid(row=8, column=8)
button8i.grid(row=8, column=9)
button8j.grid(row=8, column=10)
button9a.grid(row=9, column=1)
button9b.grid(row=9, column=2)
button9c.grid(row=9, column=3)
button9d.grid(row=9, column=4)
button9e.grid(row=9, column=5)
button9f.grid(row=9, column=6)
button9g.grid(row=9, column=7)
button9h.grid(row=9, column=8)
button9i.grid(row=9, column=9)
button9j.grid(row=9, column=10)
button10a.grid(row=10, column=1)
button10b.grid(row=10, column=2)
button10c.grid(row=10, column=3)
button10d.grid(row=10, column=4)
button10e.grid(row=10, column=5)
button10f.grid(row=10, column=6)
button10g.grid(row=10, column=7)
button10h.grid(row=10, column=8)
button10i.grid(row=10, column=9)
button10j.grid(row=10, column=10)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I bet using lists and loops would help.

Comment: Making the board in a canvas out of lines+sprites, would be much simpler than all of those buttons. But you will still need to use `list`s and `for` loops as @ FredLarson pointed out.

Comment: Hi Lukas, welcome to the community. Notice that your question has nothing to do with tkinter and it's just only related to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a loop can help you:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        btn = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
        btn.grid(row=i+1, column=j+1)
```

If you need the buttons later, put them in a list, or even better, a nested list, so you can reference similarly to a 10x10 grid

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified chessboard maker. I'll just make a slight change.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        self.matrix = []
        c = ("white", "black")
        cell_colour = True
        for y in range(10):
            for x in range(10):
                button = tk.Button(self.root, width=3, fg=c[not cell_colour],
                                   bg=c[cell_colour], activebackground="red")
                self.matrix.append(button)
                button.grid(row=x, column=y, sticky="news")
                cell_colour = not cell_colour
            cell_colour = not cell_colour
        
    def mainloop(self) -> None:
        self.root.mainloop()
    
chess = Board()
chess.mainloop()
```

Here it is with buttons connected to `buttonClick` that keeps track of which button was pressed and also has active colors.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class board:

    matrix = [ ]
    c = ['white', 'black']
    d = ['yellow', 'red' ]

    def route( self, n ):
        return lambda: self.buttonClick( n )

    def __init__( self ):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.build( 1 )
        self.master.resizable( False, False )
        self.master.deiconify()

    def build( self, w ):
        for y in range( 10 ):
            for x in range( 10 ):
                button = tk.Button(
                    self.master, width = 9, height = 3,
                    foreground = self.c[w], background = self.c[1-w],
                    activeforeground = self.d[w], activebackground = self.d[1-w],
                    command = self.route( x*10+y ) )
                button.grid( row=x, column=y, sticky='nsew')
                self.matrix.append( button )
                w = 1-w
            w = 1-w

    def buttonClick( self, n ):
        print( n )
    
game = board( )
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: @TheLizzard ah you beat me to it:)

Comment: :D. Also chess boards are 8x8 not 10x10 so calling the `Board` class `chess` isn't the best idea. I forgot to change that.

Comment: @TheLizzard yeah I wrote this originally for Visual python about 8 years ago.